# Why is my sprite's costume not changing in scratch when the statement of a function becomes true?

Tags: sprite, mit-scratch

Why is my sprite's costume not changing in scratch when the statement of a function becomes true?

I have the following code:

[image: Scratch code]

For some reason it doesn't change the costume.

Comment: Where are you incrementing `# of jumps`?

Comment: What is the duration of the audio clip "Musicalizacion 3 WAV FINAL"? Please be aware that the 'forever' loop will not start until the music is over. If that's not what you want, then use block "start sound" instead of "play sound ... until done."

Answer (score 1):

Change the block "play sound ...WAV FINAL until done" to: *start* *sound* ...WAV FINAL" What's happening is that the program waits until the sound is *done* playing to then check to change the costume